# How to avoid OOP deep class hierarchies when switching to Haskell?

Tags: haskell

A game written in say C++ typically has a class hierarchy such as

- CEntity

  - CMoveable

    - CCar
    - CTank
    - CJetPack
  - CHuman

    - CPedestrian
    - CPlayer
    - CAlien
  - CRigid

    - CRock
    - CGrenade
  - CMissile
  - CGun
  - CMedkit

Now I have read that some have [argued](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/) that a class hierarchy is a wrong architecture even when using C++. But at least it attempts code reuse. And is the obvious way for being able to shove everything into one managing container since everything trivially fits into a list of CEntity.

But in any case, for someone trying to switch from C++ to Haskell for making games how does one change the architecture to fit within Haskell's functional paradigm?

Comment: The alternatives to deep inheritance hierarchies, at least the better ones, don't have the problems you allege: Code reuse is *easier* (same amount of code reuse with less adjusting of the whole hierarchy when changing things), and shoving everything into one container is also trivial since everything is an entity (not even derived from one, quite exactly a non-polymorphic entits).

Comment: Not sure I would consider 3 levels that deep, but I've come to view the automatic reach for the inheritance hammer with deep suspicion over the years and would far rather use aggregation. In a functional environment it's not a given that you need either though. Duck typing and it's consequences will be worth a look.

Comment: Since there is no serious haskell games currently present (i.e. featuring physics and advanced rendering), I suppose talking about functional alternatives to the conventional C++ approach is rather pointless (ok, let's say 'completely theoretical').

Comment: @user2894391: I think the point of this question is about maintainability, more than performance, so physics and advanced rendering are not that relevant.

Comment: @Tarmil Features I listed are just crucial for architecture design and maintainability. I believe they are good indicators of 'phase transition' between weekend projects and something worthy (from technical POV).

Comment: @user2894391 I don't think it's rhetorical. Haskell currently presents an interesting alternative to imperative programming. The fact that C++ is so widely used is because it's really great at managing your memory, but it's sometimes clunky when it gets to logic. Haskell is great in mathematical computations (physics), and has necessary low-level primitives to handle operation of large data. Modern approach to rendering is also taking *a lot* of stress from the Client/CPU side, so as long as you keep your data on GPU, you can render equally fast. It's more about getting devs to try/use it now.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Well, I won't argue, because my point was completely different. We all know what functional programming is an interesting alternative and so on. I just said that despite having all that shining abilities (which zealots love to mention), there are no haskell game engines comparable even with relatively simple enthusiast projects using conventional approach. So it is a bit early to reason about advantages of FP in this particular area. There's simply no experts at this topic today, no one will give a reliable answer at SO.

Comment: @user3974391 The fact that C++ is so widely used doesn't imply that all or even most game developers use it in a conventional way (i.e. class hierarchies)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd argue it's a mistake to translate OO code into Haskell, but instead write your game from the ground up in Haskell.

In my opinion the most appropriate tool to use for games programming is **Functional Reactive Programming**. This makes you think in terms of Behaviours and Events - your game elements change over time and you combine them and define relationships between them.

(You don't need to shove everything into a single container unless you're missing an advanced way of managing world updates and are forced to iterate along some collection applying a `.update()` method. Functional Reactive Programming is an advanced way of managing updates.)

It takes time to learn to think FRP, but the investment is worth it.

**Code reuse** is (as usual in Haskell) through

- very general type signatures - polymorphic or typeclass based
- higher order functions
- great abstractions like `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Foldable`, `Traversable`, `Monad`
- avoiding needlessly making impure code - pure code is easiest to combine and reapply
- spotting similarities in how things behave or combine - don't write the same code twice
- Scrap Your Boilerplate
- Template Haskell

these tend to apply much more widely than subtype polymorphism.

Comment: By the way, in my view, `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Foldable`, `Traversable` and `Monad` would all be called patterns in OO and you'd have to handwrite boilerplate code to implement the pattern. In Haskell, they're just there. I'd call them: `Functor` = data transformation pattern, `Applicative` = combination pattern, `Foldable` = combining visitor pattern, `Traversable` = structural visitor pattern, `Monad` = reprogram the semicolon pattern. I don't use the visitor pattern to find the sum or maximum of my tree values, I just make an instance and `foldr (+)` or `foldr max`.

Comment: "reprogram the semicolon pattern" - I like it :)

Comment: ....as did I when I first heard it, @MatthewWalton. (It's not my phrase, but I can't recall its provenance.) Of course you can't reprogram the semicolon in most languages, but that's a good name for what on the face of it seems simple and limited but turns out to be profound and transformative.

Comment: It is a simplistic analogy. `Functor` is more like a type transformation than data transformation. For example, `r->a` is a functor in `a`, and the functor's job is to transform that into `r->b`. It is a monad, too, and corresponds to `pesky global variable` pattern. Also, `(a->b)->a` is a monad in `a` - where's the semicolon in that? :) These concepts are extremely hard to even conceive of in OO

Comment: @SassaNF I agree it's a simplistic analogy; OO isn't FP and doesn't replicate it terribly well. (I had intended the phrase "data transformation" to include radically changing the data to the point of being a very different type.) You could say that the Reader monad `(r->b)` could be used to solve a similar problem to the singleton pattern; I think it's telling that a single Monad instance is itself enough to replace a pattern.

Comment: The semicolons in the `(a->b)->a` monad you mention are in `do {x<-f; y<-g; h x y}`, and they mean something _very_ different in the parser monad, for example. Thinking of `(a->b)->a` in those terms is the sort of transformative effect monads have. My analogies are simplistic, but it's the effect on your thinking that I claim is profound.

Comment: ok, I thought the semicolons they meant were the semicolons used in plain languages (I thought the analogy was used to refer to "sequencing the statements" by a monad, which I don't think is even entirely right)

Answer (score 8):

Let me first say that I don't know anything about game development, so my answer might well not apply to your question.

That being said, I think the key is to ask the question: why do you use a class hierachy in a language like C++? I think the answer is two-fold: subtype-polymorphism and code reuse.

As you have noted, using inheritance to achieve code-reuse is often criticized, and I believe rightly so. Prefer composition to inheritance is often good advice, it reduces coupling and makes things more explicit. The equivalent in Haskell is just to reuse functions, which is quite simple.

That leaves us with the second benefit: subtype-polymorphism. Haskell does not support subtypes or subtype polymorphsim, but with typeclasses it has another kind of ad-hoc polymorphism which is even more general (in that things don't need to be in a sub-type relationship to implement the same functions).

So my answer is: Think about why you would want a class hierachy. If you want code reuse, then just reuse code by factoring it into sufficiently general functions and reuse these, if you want polymorphism use type classes.

There are some instances where subtyping is actually useful and thus it is sometimes a drawback that Haskell does not support this, but in my experience this is quite rare. On the other hand inheritance tends to be overused in languages such as C++ or Java because that is the one-size-fits-all tool they provide.

In general, I agree with @enoughreptocomment's answer, namely that it is a mistake to reproduce OO designs in Haskell -- you can usually do much better! I was just trying to point out the things that class hierachies give you and how similar things can be achieved in Haskell.

**Edit** (in response to Zeta's comment):

It's true that typeclasses don't allow heterogeneous types in data types such as lists, however with an extra helper data type this can also be achieved ([stolen from the Haskell wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types)):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data ShowBox = forall s. Show s => SB s

heteroList :: [ShowBox]
heteroList = [SB (), SB 5, SB True]

instance Show ShowBox where
  show (SB s) = show s

f :: [ShowBox] -> IO ()
f xs = mapM_ print xs

main = f heteroList
```

Comment: Note that type classes won't enable you to have a list of `a`s and `b`s, even if they share the same type class.

Comment: @Zeta this is true, however it is possible to use typeclasses to do this (at the expense of additional datatype), see the edited answer above.

Comment: "Let me first say that I don't know anything about game development" shouldn't be a problem. Game development is not magically special to make good ideas stop making sense all of a sudden.

Comment: It's worth noting that while this ShowBox example does demonstrate the existential heterogeneous list, it's not a great place to use it. You'd want to constrain the existential with a more powerful typeclass (or set of typeclasses) so that when you pull it back out of the list there are still interesting operations to do to it. Otherwise, you may as well have just ran `map show` over the whole thing to begin with.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson Indeed, but the example was a simple proof that Zeta's assertion oversimplified the situation somewhat. I'd argue that existential heterogeneous lists are more often a kind of code smell than they are a great design choice.

Comment: Ah, sorry if I worded it poorly. I wrote that more for posterity and future readers than out of an assumption that the author didn't understand the limitations and alternatives surrounding existential boxing like that.

Comment: As far as the code smell goes, I'm actually increasingly a fan of existential boxes, but they really are far overkill for an example like this.

Comment: I agree with both of you and think this discussion is really good to put things into perspective. I am wondering what good these existential boxes really serve, especially since with lazy evaluation you could just provide a container with the desired results without paying for it until it is needed. I think it is somewhat comforting that this possibility exists, but I don't see too much use for it.

Comment: @Zeta This is what `Either` is for: `[Left 1, Right "Hello"] :: [Either Int String]`.

Answer (score 5):

Haskell doesn't have subtyping so its going to be hard to directly translate the hierarchy. You can try doing some crazy hack with typeclasses but [I wouldn't recommend it](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/), since it gets very complicated very quickly.

The component-based architecture you linked to is just as good for code reuse and is more easily translated into Haskell, since there are no class hierarchies.

For example, in C++ you would have a render component. In C++ you would represent this as an abstract render interface and some concrete Render classes.

```cpp
class Renderer {
    virtual void draw(double x, double y) = 0;
    virtual void frobnicate(int n) = 0;
};

class HumanRenderer: public Renderer {
  //render Players and Pedestrians...
  //(code reuse!)

  //constructor:
  HumanRenderer(int age);
};

class MedkitRenderer: public Renderer{
  //render the medkit

  //constructor:
  HumanRenderer(Color color);
};
```

In Haskell, you would do to something similar without subtyping. The type of the parent interface is just a record of functions:

```
data Renderer = Renderer {
  rendererDraw :: Double -> Double -> IO (),
  rendererFrobnicate :: Int -> IO ()
}

-- I'm putting everything in the IO monad so the code is side effecting like
--in the C++ version. If you want to avoid this mutation then this is where that 
--functional reactive programming stuff would come in.
```

and the constructors for the concrete classes are just  functions that return one of these records.

```
humanRenderer :: Int -> Renderer
humanRenderer age = -- ...

medkitRenderer :: Color -> Renderer
medkitRenderer rgb = -- ...
```

Note that since there is a single "Renderer" type, you can put different sorts of renderer in a homogenous list, just like you could in cpp (this would be much trickier to do in the typeclass approach):

```
renderers :: [Renderer]
renderers = [ humanRenderer 10, humanRenderer 20, medKitRenderer Red ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The question asks for a Haskell encoding of a class hierarchy with two goals:

1. being able to shove everything into one managing container
2. code reuse

I'll use a smaller variant of the class hierarchy from the question for my examples. The easiest way to achieve goal 1 is to have a single algebra data type for entities. We can then use lists or arrays or whatever container we want that contain entities. So we want:

```
data Entity = ...
type ExampleContainer = [Entity]
```

How should we fill in the `...`? I first show a naive approach, analyze why it fails to provide reuse, and then turn this insight into a more sophisticated approach that provides reuse.

### Naive approach, bad reuse :(

There are multiple kinds of entities in the CEntity class hierarchy, so we could use multiple constructors for the Entity data type:

```
data Entity
  = Car     Position Velocity Color
  | Player  Position Velocity Gun
  | Door    Position Key
  | Rock    Position
```

Every leaf of the class hierarchy corresponds to a constructor, but the intermediate classes don't show up. This leads to a duplication in the datatype declaration: We repeat `Position` and `Velocity` multiple times. This duplication on the type level also influences the rest of our program: For example, a function that moves objects with a velocity one step forward would look like:

```
move :: Entity -> Entity
move (Car    position velocity color) = Car  (position + velocity) velocity color
move (Player position velocity gun)   = Tank (position + velocity) velocity gun
move (Door   poosition key)           = Door position key
move (Rock   position)                = Rock position
```

The duplication of the `Position` and `Velocity` fields indeed leads to a duplication of the `position + velocity` formula. Maybe if we reuse the `Position` and `Velocity` fields in the algebraic data type, we can also reuse the `position + velocity` formula?

### Sophisticated approach, better reuse :)

We restructure our algebraic data so that common fields are shared. All entities have a position, but the other fields differ according to what kind of entity we have:

```
data Entity
  = Entity Position EntityInfo
```

Moving objects have a velocity but fixed objects don't:

```
data EntityInfo
  = Moving Velocity Moving
  | Fixed Fixed
```

A moving object can be a car or a player:

```
data Moving
  = Car Color
  | Player Name
```

And a fixed object can be door or a rock:

```
data Fixed
  = Door Key
  | Rock
```

So we still have the four constructors `Car`, `Player`, `Door` and `Rock`, but in addition we have the constructors `Entity`, `Moving` and `Fixed` to store information that is available for multiple kinds of entities. These additional constructors correspond to the intermediate classes in the class hierarchy. Note that we only mention `Position` and `Velocity` once, so hopefully the code duplication in the `move` function should go away. And indeed:

```
move :: Entity -> Entity
move (Entity position (Moving velocity info))
  = Entity (position + velocity) (Moving velocity info)
move (Entity position (Fixed info)) = Entity position (Fixed info)
```

Now, the formula `position + velocity` only appears once, as we hoped.

### Summary

One approach for encoding a deep class hierarchy is by algebraic data types. Every class corresponds to a constructor, and every class that has subclasses also corresponds to a data type. If we avoid field duplication in these data type, we also avoid code duplication in the code that manipulates values of the data types.

Comment: Arent algebraic data types kind of the opposite of class hierarchies though, from an [expression problem](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ExpressionProblem) point of view? ADTs make it easy to add new method but hard to add new entities while the class hierarchy is about keeping the set of method fixed but making it easy to add new entities.

Comment: missingno, yes that's correct, but it is not necessarily a problem. You can always change the Haskell code to add more constructors. What you cannot do is add more constructors *in a different module* without changing the original code. But the question didn't ask about modular extensibility.

Answer (score 1):

It is, I think, a rather hard question to answer, because it might be highly dependent on personal coding style. I've switched from large inheritance hierarchies to different designs *way before* I've written anything in Haskell.

And from my observations, code reuse in Haskell is much *simpler* than in C++ or Java anyway, because pretty much everything you use, every primitive and element behaves in a predictable, similar way and can be operated on using a small set of very generic functions. That means that as long as you adhere to the rules governing Haskell idiomatic constructs when creating your entities, the fact that the code isn't duplicating should come naturally.

As an example, take a look at `fmap`. It's an extremely simple, yet an extremely powerful tool. I can imagine you using your player as a Functor and mapping items over him to make them have an effect. You only write the actual effect and and define the player; you don't have to be concerned with how they will have to interact, because there are "standard" ways of doing that.

**TL;DR** Higher-order functions and typeclasses prove themselves to be really nice when dealing with more complicated logic. *Lenses* simplify operations on nested data. You have to rethink some things and probably you won't find direct counterparts, but it's certainly possible to write good game code in Haskell.